# What http result should I return for duplicate entry

Tags: rest, http

I have an api that let users create a person object and im creating it in the mysql db, currently when mysql returns a `MySQLException if  t.errorMessage.errorCode == 1062` i return the user 400 with message that a person with this id already exist, should I instead return 409?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, keep the following in mind (quoted from the [chapter 6](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm) of Fielding's dissertation that defines the REST architectural style):

> The resource is not the storage object. The resource is not a mechanism that the server uses to handle the storage object. The resource is a conceptual mapping [...]

Abstracting the database concerns, if there's a conflict in the *state of the resource*, the [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code seems to be the most suitable code for this situation. The server also should return details about the conflict in the response payload:

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]